# Tick or spider?

Tags: bugs

Northeast America. Does this appear to be a tick or a spider?

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That’s what I thought. I was looking for the segmentation part but ain’t no expert. Based on that website and some others. It seems segmented.

Answer (score 4):

It is a spider, having a segmented body. This site [How Are Ticks Related to Spiders?](https://tickcontrol.com/blog/how-are-ticks-related-to-spiders/) says

> . . . spiders have segmented bodies while ticks do not, and Spiders have a separate cephalothorax and abdomen. Ticks have small, flat, unsegmented bodies that enable them to attach easily to a host

Here are pictures from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider) which show the difference.
Left: spider . . . Right: tick.

[image]

They both have 8 legs and an exoskeleton but their bodies are quite different. Clearly the OP's photo has a segmented body.

Comment: Indeed. It is a [jumping spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider) (Salticidae) :)